# AWS Instance Storage Usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance which is dedicated to a small WordPress site. I have stopped the instance because I am basically just parking the site for now. The instance has an EBS volume, which is 10 gigabytes. I am sure the instance mustn't actually use that much. Is there a way I can safely reduce the size of the EBS volume so I don't have to pay extra?

Comment: Increasing the size is pretty straightforward. Decrease is possible but involves more steps. 10GB will cost you 80 cents a month.  How much are you trying to reduce it to?

Comment: The minimum necessary size would be good. I realize the fees are not that high, but I am economical.

Answer (score 0):

Take a snapshot and store in s3 glacier, and get rid of the EBS volume. When you are ready to use, hydrate it from glacier and you should be good to go.

Comment: I like this idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Except too bad it doesn't work. People are saying it isn't possible to store snapshots in Glacier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236115/is-it-possible-to-move-ec2-volumes-to-amazon-glacier-without-having-to-download Nor can I see any option in the snapshots area of EC2 control panel.

Comment: ah ic, I am presuming all the website settings and code are in the wordpress folder. If so, you can just zip your wordpress folder and upload to glacier. Getting setup to run the site again will be a bit of more work.

Comment: I've decided to use a WordPress plugin called UpdraftPlus to produce a full backup of the WordPress instance. I downloaded the backup files to my laptop, and zipped them (the zip file is about 12 megs). UpdraftPlus is very reliable when restoring backups to clone instances of WordPress. I will just store the zip file on my laptop until I need my WordPress website again, at which time I will restore my backup into a fresh EC2 instance created from the Bitnami WordPress AMI. I just need to hope there are no major version hops or anything that will render my backups useless in the meantime.

Comment: I have left the comment to document my choice of action, but it didn't answer the original question so I am going to leave off here.

Answer (score 0):

What about just create a snapshot and then from this snapshot create a new instance but on the storage step dedicate less space. What is the total amount of space your WordPress occupies?

Comment: I know that in this case you may have your WordPress corrupted. Your Public DNS Name will be changed and Blog is Broken. No worries, you will be able to fix it. Find tutorial by following the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html