# Unable to upload files to Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

I have an AWS EC2 instance yielding some data, which in turn is meant to be moved to AWS Glacier. According to [Is it possible to move EC2 volumes to Amazon Glacier without having to download and upload it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236115/is-it-possible-to-move-ec2-volumes-to-amazon-glacier-without-having-to-download/31236642#31236642) there are only two ways to put data in Glacier:

1. Upload data directly as described in [Using Amazon Glacier with the AWS Command Line Interface - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-glacier.html)
2. Copy/move the data to S3 and create a lifecycle rule.

Unfortunately neither approaches worked, meaning that I access my vault and nothing is there, even after a week. Furthermore once I complete the example provided, the "**aws glacier describe-vault**" command 
outputs:

```
{
    "SizeInBytes": 0, 
    "NumberOfArchives": 0, 
    "CreationDate": "2018-08-14T12:59:31.456Z", 
    ... 
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you used option #1, did you receive an error message when you created an Archive within the Vault? Are you sure that you ran the command in the same region as your vault?

Comment: i) no; ii) yes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Option #2, where you created a lifecycle rule to move objects to Glacier, **you will not see the objects in Glacier itself**.

When Amazon S3 lifecycles objects to Glacier, the objects are kept in a Glacier vault that is managed by Amazon S3 and is not visible to you. Instead, the objects in S3 will show a Storage Class of `Glacier`, which means that the object metadata is kept in S3 (name, size, etc) but the actual *contents* of the object has been moved to Glacier.

As long as you can see the Storage Class of `Glacier`, your objects have been successfully moved to Glacier.